# Why the "Group Table View Background Color" was deprecated?

Tags: ios, uikit

Some bug was found on the new iPad, tableView's background becomes totally transparent.
And the issue is caused by "Group Table View Background Color" was deprecated. (Although it totally fine on iPhone5 with iOS6.0)

I understand most of the deprecates are with solid reason, but why this deprecate for? Any particular advantage developers can take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Apple discussion boards, one Apple engineer explained that the table view background was tweaked in iOS 6 to a point where it couldn't be represented by a UIColor anymore. Table views now use a background view instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will be appreciate if you can let me know the link of the discussion board

Comment: There are several engineers here who give some explanation on how to work with table view backgrounds in iOS 6: https://devforums.apple.com/message/734286#734286